# How Can I do this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a firefox plugin and this plugin supports javascript and jquery codes. I want to add click function to this code at the below but I couldn't do it.

```
<jfk-button tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" class="p6n-loading-button jfk-button goog-inline-block jfk-button-action" jfk-button-style="ACTION" ng-if="!apiCtrl.api.enabled" pan-loading-button="apiCtrl.apiEnablementCtrl.apiStateRpcDefer reds[apiCtrl.api.id].promise" pan-loading-button-regular-text="Enable API" pan-loading-button-loading-text="Enabling" jfk-on-action="apiCtrl.toggleApi()"><span class="p6n-loading-button-regular-text">Enable API</span><span class="p6n-loading-button-loading-text">Enabling</span><pan-loader><div class="p6n-ls-container" ng-class="{'p6n-ls-offline' : isOffline}"> <span class="p6n-ls-node"></span> <span class="p6n-ls-node"></span></div></pan-loader></jfk-button>
```

Codes that I tried:

```
$('.p6n-loading-button jfk-button goog-inline-block jfk-button-action').click();
$('.p6n-loading-button jfk-button goog-inline-block jfk-button-action').eq(0).click();
$('.p6n-loading-button').click();
```

My purpose is adding click function to that jfk code. Thanks :)

Comment: you should try `$('.p6n-loading-button .jfk-button goog-inline-block .jfk-button-action')` Though last one should have been work at-least..Are you producing this dom dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$('jfk-button').click(function(){
      console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: `console.log()` is better for debugging than alerts

Comment: I received this when I tried your code: [Object HTMLElements]

Comment: @ZachSaucier can you write me the code with console.log() please?

Comment: @JulianoBomin sure, the alert is just to prove its working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.p6n-loading-button.jfk-button.goog-inline-block .jfk-button-action').click();
```

When setting up the handler you need to use the CSS-class of the target object. Look at the dots (`.`).

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't worked. <jfk-button is not seeing the classic-click code because <jfk-button is not a standart element like div. Because of that browser is not running this classic-click code. Any thoughts?